# Android app suddenly stops

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am learning the basics of android programming. Now I have made a Life Cycle test. The list activity works fine, but when I attempt to open the Life Cycle test, the app stops and closes. I have got the same problem on several devices. These are my codes:

(Manifest)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.badlogic.androidgames"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidBasicsStarter"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

</manifest>
```

(AndroidBasicsStarter.java)

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AndroidBasicsStarter extends ListActivity {
    String tests[] = { "LifeCycleTest", "SingleTouchTest", "MultiTouchTest", "KeyTest",
            "AccelerometerTest", "AssetsTest", "ExternalStorageTest", "SoundPoolTest",
            "MediaPlayerTest", "FullScreenTest", "RenderViewTest", "ShapeTest", "BitmapTest",
            "FontTest", "SurfaceViewTest"
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        String testName = tests[position];
        try {
            Class clazz = Class
                    .forName("com.badlogic.androidgames." + testName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(LifeCycleTest.java)

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LifeCycleTest extends Activity {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    TextView textView;

    private void log(String text) {
        Log.d("LifeCycleTest", text);
        builder.append(text);
        builder.append('\n');
        textView.setText(builder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(builder.toString());
        setContentView(textView);
        log("created");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        log("resumed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        log("paused");

        if (isFinishing()) {
            log("finishing");
        }
    }
}
```

I use *Eclipse* on Windows 7. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Every activity that you plan to use in your app needs to be declared in the manifest of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `LifeCycleTest` activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name=".LifeCycleTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include both your activities inside your Manifest file. It should look something like this.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidBasicsStarter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LifeCycleTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```